# Duplicate item in tableview when using searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

This is the searchbar delegate that i use

```
 func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.characters.count >= 2 {
        self.setupinbox(searchText)
        }
    }
```

This is the function to get data from server

```
func setupinbox(q : String) {

        arrayOfRels.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "URL")!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let data = "devicetoken=\(devicetoken!)&q=\(q)&user_id=\(userid)"
        request.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }

            if let response = response {

                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                    {

                        do {
                            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSArray
                            let json = JSON(jsonData)

                            for (_, subJSON): (String, JSON) in json[0]["interests"] {

                                let title = subJSON["title"].string
                                let eID = subJSON["ID"].string
                                let count = subJSON["count"].string
                                let rel1 = InboxInterests(title: title!,eventID : NSInteger(eID!)!, count: count!)
                                self.arrayOfRels.append(rel1)

                            }

                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print(error)
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    } else {

                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Connection Failed", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

                        }))
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    }
                )}
        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

When i type searchbar slowly, everything is ok, i see results correctly.

But when i type 2 letters very quickly, i get duplicate item.

[image]

I also get duplicate items when i remove letters quickly

Tried something like delaying the `textDidChange` but it didnt work.

Any idea what causes this and how can i fix?

Comment: Do you have 2 items at arrayOfRels ?

Comment: You are loading data asynchronously. Shouldn't you be cancelling any pending requests before starting new ones?

Comment: @Sebastian yeah i realized that array has 2 items when i quickly type

Comment: @beyowulf can you show me how to do that?

Comment: You could create an `NSURLSessionTask?` property. Something like "currentTask." This will allow you to hold a reference to the most recent fetch request. At the start of `setupInbox` you can cancel it `self.currentTask.cancel()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put an extra line of code:

```
do {
arrayOfRels.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
........
```

Comment: This may suffice for a toy project, but it's not scalable.

Comment: @NRitH can you tell me what is the best way to prevent this?